# What is the name of Vishnu incarnation who performed the Meenakshi Sundareshwarar Kalyanam?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

From the story of Meenakshi Thirukalyanam, we infer that Lord Kallazhagar, a form of Lord Vishnu, did not attend the marriage.

But we are told that Lord Vishnu gave away Meenakshi Amman during the marriage. So who is this Lord Vishnu?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Lord Vishnu himself present in Goddess Meenakshi's marriage. The 5th chapter of Halashya Mahatmya mentioned it.

And, Lord Kallazhagar is established by King Gunasekhara, the grandfather of Goddess Meenakshi. The 3rd chapter of Halashya Mahatmya menriones it as Gunasekhara esrablished Vishnu's temple at East, Lord Kallazhagar's temple is also situated at east of Madurai.

So, the conclusion is:-

- Lord Vishnu is not taking any avatars during the marriage and it's him.
- Lord Kallazhagar is Lord Vishnu himself, but appeared before Meenakshi's arrival.

---

Ok, that's it. I hope your doubt is cleared.